# Performance in reading and writing rasters using Python and GDAL

Tags: python, pyqgis, gdal, geoprocessing

I've been thinking about how to improve my plugin's performance, which involves a lot of operations in chain (always getting the result of the previous algorithm). One of the problems I noticed is that using GDAL, for example, it is always necessary to wait for the result of the previous algorithm to be fully persisted in a file so that later it can be used in another algorithm. But this results in a lot of openings, readings and writings to the disk.

I think it would be interesting to have an approach where each algorithm (those that come ready-made in GDAL) could be connected to another algorithm in such a way that each block read and processed in the first algorithm would be published to the subsequent algorithm... and so on, until the last algorithm in the chain finally writes the result to disk.

Is this already possible to be done with python + gdal? If not, would it be a viable idea?

Comment: You can avoid disk writes by writing into memory https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mem.html. It is also possible to do rather complicated things with VRT files https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html.

Comment: Or https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/memory.html.

Comment: I'll take a look at this. But as I understand it, the raster is written entirely to RAM. Wouldn't it be too costly if we were using a very large raster?

Comment: You may process the data by spatial windows (e.g. read a chunk of data, process, go on to the next one). Also, have a look at the virtual memory mapping functions implemented in [RFC45](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc45_virtualmem.html).